# Mac terminal zsh command not found - how to solve?

Tags: macos, terminal, command, zsh

I get with carious terminal commands the following error:

zsh: command not found: -X

What is this error?
I get this with CD as well for instance, but not with all commands. LS for instance works fine.

Comment: This might be more appropriate in [apple.se]?

Comment: Stackoverflow is for questions about programming, not general computer usage or troubleshooting; [Superuser](https://superuser.com) or possibly [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com) would be better places to ask about things like this. In any case, the first thing to do is probably to run `set -x` to turn on shell command tracing, and see what's actually happening as the commands run. Also, try to characterize exactly when it happens (e.g. does it *always* happen when you use `cd`, or only sometimes?).

Comment: First of all, I guess you mean `cd` and `ls`, not `CD` and `LS`. As for your actual problem, I guess that you run some code automatically before or after each command execution. This could be a buggy prompt- or pre-command-definition. Therefore I would first try to start a zsh which is as clean as possible. For intance, what happens if you open a new subshell with the command `zsh -f`. Do you still see the error message?

Answer (score 0):

export PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).